# Not able to link created tenant to Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am not able to link the tenant to Azure AD B2C. Around 8 tenants are created but none of them are listed in the drop down. I am using my personal subscription Pay as you go.

Please find attached the screen shot.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

At least one of two problems could be going on.

First (and most likely) you are following old instructions which include separate create and link steps (and confusingly separate create and link steps still exist in the portal).  Recently, linking the tenant to a subscription was integrated into the create-a-tenant flow, so this second step is unnecessary and hence, the new tenant is not available for linking to a subscription -- because **it was linked as soon as it was created**.

A second (less likely) issue can be gleaned from the docs [docs for linking a B2C Tenant to your subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/billing#link-an-azure-ad-b2c-tenant-to-a-subscription) contain these notes:

> 7. Select an Azure AD B2C Tenant from the dropdown. Only tenants for which you're a global administrator and that are not
>    already linked to a subscription are shown. The Azure AD B2C Resource
>    name field is populated with the domain name of the Azure AD B2C
>    tenant you select.
> 8. Select an active Azure Subscription of which you're an owner.

which means that in order to create the link, you must be both (A) An owner on the subscription that you are linking to the tenant and (B) the Global Administrator on the B2C Tenant.  If you don't have both permissions, then the Tenant won't show up in the list of tenants available to link to your subscription.

The identity that you used when creating the tenant is automatically a global admin on the new tenant -- but you may not be an owner on the current subscription.  In my case, the owner role is managed by my company, so I had to delete the newly created B2C tenant, and create a new B2C Tenant using an identity that was already an owner on the subscription, which ensured that the identity that was used when creating the link was both an owner on the current subscription and a global admin on the B2C Tenant.

An alternative to deleting the B2C Tenant and starting over would be to grant the global admin role for the new B2C Tenant to an identity that is already an owner on the subscription that you want to link to the tenant.